# Why does this query have two selects?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query :

```
SELECT         WorkId, RegisterDate, sum(RoomType1) As RoomType1, sum(RoomType2) As RoomType2, sum(RoomType3) As RoomType3, sum(RoomType4) As RoomType4, sum(RoomType5) As RoomType5, sum(RoomType6) As RoomType6, sum(RoomType7) As RoomType7, sum(RoomType8) As RoomType8
FROM (

SELECT     dbo.[Work].WorkId, dbo.[Work].RegisterDate, 

case dbo.Floor.RoomType when 1 then 1 else 0 end as RoomType1,
        case dbo.Kat.RoomType when 2 then 1 else 0 end as RoomType2,


FROM            dbo.Belediye INNER JOIN
                         dbo.[Is] ON dbo.Municipality.MunicipalityId= dbo.[Is].MunicipalityWorkId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Look ON dbo.[Work].LookWorkId = dbo.Look.LookId ,
WHERE        (dbo.Look.LocationIS NOT NULL)

) E
GROUP BY WorkId,
```

This query works as expected, but I can't understand why it has two selects, why does it need them? Please explain it to me. Thanks.

Comment: The inner select is called a derived table. Very handy when doing `group by` to avoid writing complex expressions twice. (Which isn't even allowed according to ANSI SQL.)

Comment: Doesn't seem like it's really needed in this case. You can do the grouping in one select and do the `sum(case... end)` stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suspected this query dont need *two selects* and could be rewritten without sub-query:

```
SELECT  i.IsId, 
        i.KayitTarihi, 
        SUM(case k.OdaTipi when 1 then 1 else 0 end) as RoomType1,
        SUM(case k.OdaTipi when 2 then 1 else 0 end) as RoomType2,
        SUM(case k.OdaTipi when 3 then 1 else 0 end) as RoomType3,
        SUM(case k.OdaTipi when 4 then 1 else 0 end) as RoomType4,
        SUM(case k.OdaTipi when 5 then 1 else 0 end) as RoomType5,
        SUM(case k.OdaTipi when 6 then 1 else 0 end) as RoomType6,
        SUM(case k.OdaTipi when 7 then 1 else 0 end) as RoomType7,
        SUM(case k.OdaTipi when 8 then 1 else 0 end) as RoomType8
FROM dbo.Belediye b
INNER JOIN dbo.[Is] i
    ON b.BelediyeId = i.BelediyeIsId 
INNER JOIN dbo.YerGorme yg
    ON i.YerGormeIsId = yg.YerGormeId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Kat k
    ON yg.YerGormeId = k.YerGorme_YerGormeId
WHERE yg.Lokasyon IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY i.IsId, i.KayitTarihi
```

Note: use [table aliases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx)